# TypeScript How to set info for an Interface that is referenced in another Interface

Tags: json, typescript, class, interface

Below is the code that I am using to update a basic address holding interface. I'm having trouble accessing the Address interface that is referenced in the Park interface. Why am I having an issue with the constructor that I have created, to update the Address interface with the address for the info?

```
interface Park {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    address: Address;

}
interface Address {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zip: string;
}

class ArkEncounter implements Park {
    name: string;
    image: string;
    address: Address;

    setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    setImage(image: string) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    setAddress(address: Address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
    getImage(): string {
        return this.image;
    }
    getAddress(): Address {
        return this.address;
    }

    constructor(name: string, image: string, address: Address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.address = address;
    }

    printInfo() {
        console.log(`The ${this.name} is located at ${this.address.street}, ${this.address.city}     ${this.address.zip}`);
    }
}

let ArkPark = new ArkEncounter('Ark Encounter', 'https://assets.answersingenesis.org/img/cms/content/contentnode/og_image/ark-encounter-aerial2020.jpg', '1 Ark Encounter Dr, Willianstown, KY 41097');
```

I was expecting this format to change the Address interface, but I'm not sure of the correct way to implement that when calling the constructor.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  [Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) just describe the shape of JavaScript objects. Does this question mean you don't know how to use [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types)?  If so, does [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOlERN) clear it up for you? If that works for your needs I could maybe write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! I’m still learning how things work here. Basically, I’m wanting to update the Address interface strings that are linked in the Park interface through the constructor that I created. I don’t know how to update the Address parameters, which is the 3rd input in the constructor, when invoking the constructor I created to create the new ‘’’ let ArkPark’’’. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really, sorry. Did you look at the playground link I included in my comment?

Comment: @jcalz  Yep, that actually fixes the issue that I was having! I did have to remove the extends to Park, because it wanted additional inputs, which is fine. Thank you! So, is that the proper way to access object types when the interfaces are set up the way that I have them?

Comment: What does “remove the extends to Park” mean?  What “extends”?   My suggested approach in the playground link is how people use objects, yes. Shall I write up an answer post here or is there something I’m missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah go ahead and write an answer post. I miss spoke, I was looking at a different piece of code that was similar. What you did in the playground works correctly for what code I displayed with the problem I was facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third constructor parameter for `ArkEncounter` is of the `Address` [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces), an [object type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) defined as

```
interface Address {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zip: string;
}
```

That means an `Address` should be an object with (at least) those four named properties each of which are of type `string`.  A `string` like `'1 Ark Encounter Dr, Willianstown, KY 41097'` doesn't work, because strings don't have any of those properties.  That's why you get an error.

But if you want an object, you can create one fairly easily. JavaScript and TypeScript support [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for you to easily create and initialize objects.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const implausibleFloatingMenagerieAddress: Address = {
  street: '1 Ark Encounter Dr',
  city: "Willianstown",
  state: "KY",
  zip: "41097"
};
```

Note that I [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the `implausibleFloatingMenagerieAddress` variable as having type `Address`, but this isn't necessary.  If you leave off the annotation the compiler will infer a type equivalent to `Address`:

```
const implausibleFloatingMenagerieAddress = {
  street: '1 Ark Encounter Dr',
  city: "Willianstown",
  state: "KY",
  zip: "41097"
};

// inferred as type:
/* const implausibleFloatingMenagerieAddress: {
    street: string;
    city: string;
    state: string;
    zip: string;
} */
```

Either way you can then pass that into the `ArkEncounter` constructor without error:

```
let arkPark = new ArkEncounter(
  'Ark Encounter',
  'https://assets.answersingenesis.org/img/cms/'
  + 'content/contentnode/og_image/ark-encounter-aerial2020.jpg',
  implausibleFloatingMenagerieAddress
); // okay
```

Or, if you want, you can just use the object literal directly without assigning it first to a variable:

```
let arkPark = new ArkEncounter(
  'Ark Encounter',
  'https://assets.answersingenesis.org/img/cms/'
  + 'content/contentnode/og_image/ark-encounter-aerial2020.jpg',
  {
    street: '1 Ark Encounter Dr',
    city: "Willianstown",
    state: "KY",
    zip: "41097"
  }
); // okay
```

---

Object types are fundamental to how JavaScript and TypeScript work, so if you haven't already, I recommend that you read through [the TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApyga2QbwFDLIhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3AcsCXPRdbQ84XABMBUCFSqUAgkJFjmeAL55QkWIhRThoqrhY0REMJT28WCYGACeRniCa6wcSNbq2+yAF7AADs5OK8CAA2cGLIElgAoiAIAPYAruDQrCRegRBk4NroWDqExGS+rixsHFzGRfzSWpJVsni6BgBypBAAFPllNvQAlLmEyGAAFsBUAHQdyAC8RC1uioRUBgCS7JytJZyFPX2EQyOjGyjTh3MNYBoyVK2CmmI1t1S9+P0Dw2M3l1PIH1qnhJxgZpkVrdLY7ZAiMBxKAgV77Dp-ZAAlalEFg579SHQ2F7MYnFjzJEGC5aNFhWraDGELEwuHvCmnUwxEB6OIIMAxKDtFpbAA0yVKfO+FPulyeLF2b3GLS+CIldIOqyOAs4bkl+x+oWmmqojMIXhcYCWIBgMRB4NiLJiaVGgRi9FaAAMACqDFAAEhwuOlZHkrG0doQjggAm+YGQnu9OtGeggBnk-MjUujZksfpeSY1FNGni88kd3VO-ktNGSqTgcSowAARmkAGJ2xwMACyEGInDoEBJWr6sYMlAA5ABGMI5KKxBIqZAAESgA95pnMVmQACIAOrAQKBYBwFkcgDuIBXC4WDicq4A0gBNY8sXOUFcAFiHAAYAJwAdhXCmYAHoAFTICW4ZsOWlY1vWjZgC2balJ23biOCfaGNwLh2C8qbLuU6H9DQwZbGqHjeARCjIP+v71Gk4YYJg2TYNMIAQPuo6YOO8SJFyLADuE2BsZO0DzlxgxgGAXjiL+v4hIsYDvCy+7QFWthtqI+ycvQv5sOpCAkFQv4DiwADUyADpakDgL+pltmAIAxAIEC-vaAD6hySVgAC0bYThxblwNAO6BAATC+QWjAAVl49CCYQoHBOBtYQA2MRNrYrbtn5XYUnghaUQY3xYHRAWykxLF8RxrRcTxyClSoUXGcJoniZJYgGLJVDyVAimcIxVZjGpGkkFpOl6YZxmWeZY3WbZ9lOS5NEedE7EqD5flwIFwUvmFEW1VSqFxihw4sVVC38VAM5zie-SYQ+G5bjue4xIet4vHh54rteT39Peq7Pu+X4EllchAA)